# Locating href element in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-rc, selenium-ide, selenium-webdriver

Below is my code

```
<TD ALIGN="LEFT" width="65%" id="oldcontent" >3. Download csv template
    <a href="javascript:doformsubmit('3');"><IMG src="images/date_pick.gif" border=0></a>
</TD>
```

How do i locate a href element which has javascript function calling and also there is no id present.Thanks in advance for help

Am answering my own question:The below syntax works

```
assertTrue(selenium.isElementPresent("//a[@href=\"javascript:doformsubmit('3');\"]"));
```

Comment: What do you want to do after locating?? I mean click.. find attribute..??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the appropiate Xpath expression (something like //a[(@href='javascript:doformsubmit('3');')]), check this [post](http://www.theautomatedtester.co.uk/tutorials/selenium/selenium_xpath.htm) for more examples.

Comment: Nope i have tried it selenium.getText("//a[@href='/javascript:doformsubmit('1');']");          It results in parsing error

Comment: you should escape the single quotes

Answer (score 0):

U could use BeautifulSoup to read the source of the webpage.

The following solution is made in python, but u should be able to use the similar thing in java. EDIT: Except BeautifulSoup is not available for java :) => u should switch to python.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(br.page_source)
tmp = soup.findAll('a')
for t in tmp:
     string =  t['href']
```

Then u could use regular expression to catch every href that has javascript.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do it is -

> driver.findElement(By.linkText("javascript:doformsubmit('3');"));

If your intention is something like clicking the href you can actually use the TD for that which as I see can be easily located as it has an id.